# AngularJS module.directive not responding consistently

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 directives that have slightly different algorithms to parse an input value.

```
angular.module('numeric', []).directive('doublesrange', function() {...} );   
angular.module('numeric', []).directive('integersrange', function() {...} );  
angular.module('numeric', []).directive('doublesnorange', function() {...} );
```

They basically parse values from a text box.

```
<td><input ng-model="odSphere" class="doublesnorange" minvalue="-25" maxvalue="25"></td>
```

The problem is, only 'doublesnorange' is responding.  I've seen all three work during development, but when I added the third one, the other two stopped working.  They didn't respond when I undid the changes, either.

The directive content is working, if I place the 'doublesrange' code under 'doublesnorange', it will execute.  Does anybody know why the first two would fail to respond?

Comment: It is really hard to help you not seeing full code in question.

Comment: can you share the directive code also possible create a working demo using http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem, is that every time you call **angular.module('numeric', [])** numeric module is being redeclared. You need to declare it only once, and reference later.

To reference module you should not use second argument: **angular.module('numeric')**. So correct code is:

```
angular.module('numeric', []).directive('doublesrange', function() {...} );   
angular.module('numeric').directive('integersrange', function() {...} );  
angular.module('numeric').directive('doublesnorange', function() {...} );
```

You can go one step further and use chaining to declare multiple directive for a single module:

```
angular.module('numeric', [])
    .directive('doublesrange', function() {...} )
    .directive('integersrange', function() {...} )
    .directive('doublesnorange', function() {...} );
```

Comment: My IDE gave an error for the second example, but the first allowed all three directives to work.  Thanks!

Comment: The semicolons on the second example are the problem. You just need one semicolon at the end since it's supposed to be chained.

Comment: Ops, removed semicolons