# Angular (Typescript) virtually identical directives. One renders, one doesn't

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

We have a page that is meant to display two ui-grids with two sets of data.  We setup a common base controller to handle setup of the grid options, filtering, etc, and then derived two controllers from that base class, one for each grid.  We also created a Directive for each grid.

This directive is rendering:

```
namespace Directives {
'use strict';

export class SecondGridDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    static $inject: Array<string> = [];

    static instance(): ng.IDirective {
        return new SecondGridDirective();
    }

    scope: IGridDirectiveScope = { options: '=' };
    templateUrl: string = 'app/areas/blah/views/gridTemplate.html';
    restrict: string = 'E';
    controller: typeof Controllers.SecondGridController = Controllers.SecondGridController;
    controllerAs: string = 'vm';
    bindToController: boolean = true;
    transclude: boolean = true;
}

angular
    .module('Directives', [])
    .directive('secondGridDirective', SecondGridDirective.instance);
}
```

This directive is NOT rendering:

```
namespace Directives {
'use strict';

export class FirstGridDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    static $inject: Array<string> = [];

    static instance(): ng.IDirective {
        return new FirstGridDirective();
    }

    scope: IGridDirectiveScope = { options: '=' };
    templateUrl: string = 'app/areas/blah/views/gridTemplate.html';
    restrict: string = 'E';
    controller: typeof Controllers.FirstGridController = Controllers.FirstGridController;
    controllerAs: string = 'vm';
    bindToController: boolean = true;
    transclude: boolean = true;
}

angular
    .module('Directives', [])
    .directive('firstGridDirective', FirstGridDirective.instance);
}
```

Lastly, the html that they are plugged into:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="SecondGridController as ctrl">
    <second-grid-directive options="ctrl.gridOptions"></second-grid-directive>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="FirstGridController as ctrl">
    <first-grid-directive options="ctrl.gridOptions"></first-grid-directive>
</div>
```

The issue we are having is that the second-grid-controller renders, but first-grid-controller does not.  We have tried commenting out one or the other, swapping their position on the page, renaming the controllers/directives, even copying the code from the working directive and controller into the non-working one.  Nothing has had any effect.  We have noticed in debugging is that the constructors on both controllers fire, but the instance() method that we hand into the angular.directive function only fires on secondGridDirective.

Comment: Does the `second-grid-controller` renders without the first one?

Comment: The second-grid-controller does render, with or without the first.  first-grid-controller does NOT render, with or without the second.

Comment: Additionally, though the html shows the controllers being aliased with the same name we did try different aliases and it had no effect.

Comment: You are re creating the module again while registering second directive, specifying second argument in the module is for creating the module. Remove `[]` @ `.module('Directives', [])` from the second one, i.e `FirstGridDirective ` if that is loaded after `SecondGridDirective `.

Comment: Thank you!  One of our contractors came up with same idea this evening and I was coming back here to post on it.  It seems to be this same problem, but I didn't have the right search terms to land on it:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077273/angularjs-two-directives-with-the-same-module-name)